# __NSCFString object not being output in NSLog statement

Tags: ios, nsstring, nscfstring

I have a variable passed to a method using type NSString * that is actually showing up in the debugger:

```
po [myString class]
__NSCFString
```

If I `po myString` from a debugger prompt, I can see the value of the string. However, if I NSLog it, it does not print. From what I understand, NSString and __NSCFString are toll-free bridged, so one can be used like the other. So why is it not printing from an NSLog statement? Is there something I can do to force it?

The string is initialized thus:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)content];
```

This result variable is passed from one object to another using NSString * arguments. The NSLog statement looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"Did not find \n%@ %@\n%@",key, name, myString);
```

Output of this includes the values of `key` and `name` but not `myString`. If I set a breakpoint on the next line, I can query the value of myString using the `po` command.

Comment: Update your question with your `NSLog` as well as the code that declares and assigns a value to the string.

Comment: Maybe __NSCFString doesn't implement -description but NSString does?

Comment: Maybe this is a clue: if I add `NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did not find \n%@ %@ %@",key, name, myString];` followed by `NSLog(@"%@",x);` then what I get is the values of `key` and `name` followed by a bunch of white space.

Comment: Was this string, by chance, initialized by deserializing JSON via Apple's NSJSONSerialization? If so, I'm having the same issue. The good news is it otherwise acts the same.

Comment: It's been so long, I cannot recall.